# `man -H` always opens a non-existent file in browser

Tags: man, browser, man-db

I'm trying to use the command `/usr/bin/man -H 3 free` to open the manpage in my browser, but each time I run the command, the browser opens a non-existing file and of course the page cannot be displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

My `man` command is supplied by [`man-db`](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/man-db/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least on my system (Arch Linux, man-db 2.9.4, Firefox 88.0), `man` creates a temporary directory in `/tmp/`, writes the generated HTML file in it, invokes the browser with the HTML file as an argument and, when the browser process exits, removes the temporary directory (to clean things up, I guess).

While this creates no issue with some browsers (e.g. Lynx), a race condition may occur with others (Firefox, in my case; I also briefly tested Chromium, getting similar results). As far as I can see, the HTML file is correctly opened if `man` opens a new browser window. On the other hand, if the man page is opened as a new tab in an existing browser window, the browser process started by `man` returns early and the file is already gone when a different browser process tries to read it.

I see no `man` option aimed at preventing the temporary HTML file from being deleted. But, noting that the argument to the `-H`/`--html` option (or, equivalently, the value of the `BROWSER` environment variable) can be a shell command, a quick workaround may be:

```bsh
BROWSER='firefox %s; sleep 5' man -H 3 free
```

(`sleep` gives Firefox time to load the page before the file is deleted; of course, it will be impossible to reload it).

Or, if you are willing to implement your own mechanism for deleting the temporary HTML files:

```bsh
BROWSER='cp %s /path/to/file.html; firefox /path/to/file.html' man -H 3 free
```

(This ignores other assets that may be generated alongside the main `.html` file, which may therefore be rendered incorrectly).

Or, if you are fine with keeping the temporary directories (e.g. you do not generate lots of them, your `/tmp` is volatile and your system is rebooted regularly enough):

```bsh
BROWSER='firefox %s && false' man -H 3 free
```

(The temporary directory is not deleted when the browser command returns an error to `man`; as a drawback, an error message is printed because `man` thinks the browser could not be opened).

Note, also, that the `TMP` environment variable can be used to tell `man` where to create its temporary data.

Finally, the chosen workaround can be conveniently made into an alias or a function along the lines of:

```bsh
alias man='BROWSER="${BROWSER:-firefox} %s && false" man'
```

See also, for alternative ways to view man pages as HTML:

- [Is there a Linux graphics program that displays man commands in a browser?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/195179/315749)

Comment: If I unset the `BROWSER` variable before running the command, the html file is not deleted and the command fails with `man: no browser configured, so cannot show HTML output`. So it is indeed a race condition. Looking in the source, you see where they create the [folder](https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/man-db.git/tree/src/man.c#n1939) and file, and finally when they think the browser is closed, they [remove the folder](https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/man-db.git/tree/src/man.c#n1981). It looks like it has been [reported](https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?59542)

Comment: I will see if firefox has an option to not fork when being opened

Comment: @smac89 The issue seems to only concern man pages opened in existing browser instances. A clean solution is unlikely to exist, in that case the process started by `man` can only exit; the file given to it as an argument is opened by a different process after some inter-process communication `man` can't have knowledge of/control on.

Comment: A clean solution _can_ exist: Cache the opened man pages. It not only solves the problem, but can also provide a means for reducing the number of times the same html page is regenerated. You can use the stat of each file to determine if it's been in the cache for too long, then create a new copy. The last solution seems it would be the best

Comment: Another option is if there is a `MAN_BROWSER` environment variable that mandb reads and only falls back to `BROWSER` if this is not defined. Then we can use that to setup any custom options required by the browser.